# How to set Message ID in Activemq jms Queue?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have downloaded activemq version 5.8.0 and wrote the sample program for creating queues. I sent a sample message to a queue successfully.

After that I tried to set the message ID to the particular message. The message ID can be used to retrieve the specific message. I have tried to set the message ID using `message.setJMSMessageID("1234");`.

```
 public static void messagestoQueueu(){

     // JMS messages are sent and received using a Session. We will
        // create here a non-transactional session object. If you want
        // to use transactions you should set the first parameter to 'true'
        Session session;
        try {
             // Getting JMS connection from the server and starting it
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Destination represents here our queue 'TESTQUEUE' on the
        // JMS server. You don't have to do anything special on the
        // server to create it, it will be created automatically.
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("test");

        // MessageProducer is used for sending messages (as opposed
        // to MessageConsumer which is used for receiving them)
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

        // We will send a small text message saying 'Hello' in Japanese
        //BytesMessage byteMessage = session.create;  


        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setJMSType("sample");
        message.setJMSMessageID("1234");
        message.setText("sample");


        message.setJMSCorrelationID("choole");
        message.setJMSMessageID("choo01");
        message.setJMSReplyTo(destination);

        producer.send(queue, message);
        // Here we are sending the message!
        producer.send(message);
        System.out.println(message.getJMSMessageID()+" "+message.getJMSCorrelationID());
        //System.out.println("Sent message '" + message.getText() + "'");

        connection.close();
        producer.close();
        session.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it's not working. After setting the Message ID when I print it using `getJMSMessageID()` it prints random values.

How to add a message ID to the queue message?

Answer (score 8):

As per specs user cannot set JMSMessageID value. It is JMS provider specific.

```
When a message is sent, JMSMessageID is ignored. When the send method returns
it contains a provider-assigned value.
```

Comment: Thanks.Aniket.Is possible to set message ID based on JMS provider?? I want to message id.Is there any other possible? can you explain more?

Comment: No it is not possible for client application to set JMSMessageID. So if you want to co-relate messages then you can use JMSCorrelationID which is client application specific.

Comment: yes.I have used correlationID instead of messageID.But the problem is correlation ID is not unique.you can able to specify more than one message for single correlation.Now its creates a duplicate.how can i find and retrieve specific message??

Comment: Well If you are using same session to create sender and receiver than you can note down the JMSMessageID that is set after message is sent and then check the same on retrieving.

Comment: Or if you want to retrieve specific messages then while sending set some unique header property eg. `message.setStringProperty(id)` and then use Message selector to retrieve the messages.

Answer (score -1):

You can set parameters to each message:

```
message.setStringProperty("property_name",property_val);
```

That way you can pass parameters between the producer and consumer.